# Real Analysis: Suppose$ A \subset \mathbb R$ and $B=\{b:b=a$ or $ b=a^2$ for some ${a} \in A\}$. Prove that if A is countable then B is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ and $B=\{b: b=a \text{ or } b=a^2 \text{ for some } a \in A\}$. Prove that if $A$ is countable then $B$ is countable.

Comment: Here's  [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/588038).

Answer (score 3):

$B=A \cup f[A]$, the union of two countable sets, where $f(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ Union of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: As mentioned by Henno Brandsma if you take the map $f : A \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x^2,\ x \in A$ then the image of $f$ is the set $C = \{x^2 : x \in A \}$. Since cardinality of the image of $f$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $A$ you will find that $C$ is at most countable or enumerable. Observe that $B = A \cup C$. Since both of the sets $A$ and $C$ are countable so is $B$. Is it ok now @Thomas Shelby?

Comment: I'm completely okay with Henno's answer. But in my humble opinion, your answer alone doesn't provide much help.

Comment: After the comment I have made above I think that it's now quite clear. If there is some mistake let me kindly inform it. I will be ready to edit my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing:

$A_1=${$x_i | i \in \mathbb{N}$};

$A_2:=${$y_i| y_i= x_i^2, i \in \mathbb{N}$}.

$A_1$, $A_2$ are countable, so is their union

$B =A_1\cup A_2$.

Appended:

$B=${$x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,........$}.

Consider $f(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow B$.

Can you find a counting scheme, i.e. a bijective function $f$ ?